If $A^TB=0$ and $AB^T=0$, then $||A+B||_{sp}=\max\{||A||_{sp}, ||B||_{sp}\}$?
I encountered the following statement about the spectral norm of the sum of matrices.

For real matrices $A$ and $B$ of the same dimension, if $A^{T}B=0$ and $AB^{T}=0$, then $||A+B||_{sp}=\max\{||A||_{sp}, ||B||_{sp}\}$, where $||\cdot||_{sp}$ is the spectral norm.

I know that the spectral norm of A is
\begin{align}
 ||A||_{sp} = \sqrt{\lambda_{max}(A^TA)}=\sigma_{max}(A)=\max_{x\neq 0}\frac{||Ax||_2}{||x||_2},
\end{align}
where $\lambda_{max}(\cdot)$ is the largest eigenvalue, $\sigma_{max}(\cdot)$ is the largest singular value, and $||\cdot||_2$ is the $\ell_2$ norm of a vector, but I can't verify the above statement based on these definitions.
Could anyone please provide any solution or hint?

Hint: the images of $A$ and $B$ are orthogonal. The same holds for $A^T$ and $B^T$

Put $C=A+B$. The asumption entails $C^TC=A^TA+B^TB$ hence for any $x\ne 0$ you have $\|Cx\|_2^2=\|Ax\|_2^2+\|Bx\|_2^2$ hence $\|C\|_{sp}\leqslant \|A\|_{sp}+\|B\|_{sp}$. For the reverse inequality we may assume that $\|B\|_{sp}\geqslant \|A\|_{sp}$. Pick then $x\ne 0$ such that $B^TBx=\lambda_{max}(B^TB)x$. Such $x$ belongs to the image of $B^T$ so by using $AB^T=0$ we get $A^TAx=0$ and thus $\|Cx\|_2^2=\|Bx\|_2^2=\lambda_{max}\|x\|_2^2$ which entails $\|C\|_{sp}\geqslant \|B\|_{sp}$.
